# time.sleep() alternative in continuous deployment

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I have a piece of code

```
def work(param):
    time.sleep(600)
    #rest of code goes here
```

Now issue is the piece of code is going to run against multiple test cases before it is deployed and sleeping for 10mins or 600 seconds is crucial to work for implementing retry mechanism.

Let's say new developer comes to team and push a PR, I don't want his work to take 10 mins for a notification that build is passed or not.

Comment: Either disable that test case for PR tests, or find a way to make it somehow test with a shorter sleep.

Comment: Why is both the sleeping and the action part of the same code? These appear to be two separate tasks – scheduling and action.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def work(param,do_sleep = True):
    if do_sleep:time.sleep(600)
    #code goes brrrrrrr
```

With this modification when running test cases do_sleep can be set to False, meaning the 10min sleep wont trigger.